# Is it okay to connect Belden 8412 to condenser microphone?

Tags: microphone, xlr, phantom

I know there is Belden 8423 which states that it's specially made for phantom power, but I currently only have Belden 8412, since I only had dinamic microphone(before you ask, yes I am planning to buy an 8423).

I believe that it won't harm or anything, but is it okay to connect 8412 to condenser microphone?
Or should I buy the 8423 and use dinamic microphone until 8423 arrives?

Comment: condenser mics always require phantom power. You cannot do phantom power with a 2 conductor cable. wait for the 8423 cable and do it with that.

Comment: That was fast. Well then, I'll buy the 8423. Can you post that comment as an answer?

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I've tried using it with 8412... it just worked(but I'm not going to use it with 8412, that was just for testing purpose). I still believe that it won't hurt or anything(since any condenser mic should be able to handle 48v, so if it breaks or something that mic is faulty hardware), but I'll wait for 8423 to arrive. Thankfully my local audiophile shop had 8423 so I can get it tomorrow. Anyways, thank both of you.

Comment: @user287001 pins 2 and 3 are positive and inverted inputs, so connecting them together will result in no signal passing.

Comment: @Mark Apparently signal has passed so my condenser microphone just worked(I've heard some noises but still). It's not that I'll use it with 8412 though.

Comment: @Mark "condenser mics always require phantom power" I have some Shure condenser (1) mics that have an AA cell and don't need phantom power. (1) Electrets, really, but that seems to be a lost cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Belden 8412 is two conductors in one shield. It will work quite well for phantom powered condenser microphones: Connect White to pin 2 and black to pin 3 and shield to pin 1 on XLR connectors on both ends (male/female) . (A little tricky to solder the shield if you are unused to doing it, but once learned it is easy).

In fact this is how most microphone cables are made: two connectors plus braided shield. This should work for cables up to 300 meter (1000 yards) when mic and preamp follows the 48V phantom specifications fully (not all budget equipment does but will work with shorter cables). Going for three connectors, as 8423, is at first VERY unusual and secondly I would be quite surprised if it gives any better result.

Comment: Surprisingly, my setup (RME Babyface Pro fs + TLM102, heard with Campfire Audio Andromeda MW10 / beyerdynamic DT1770Pro) gave me some noises(low volume but still) when my microphone connected with 8412. Now I got an 8423 and tried using it gave me significantly reduced/almost impossible to hear the noise. Don't know what caused the noise but I'd say it's because of 8412, or maybe it's just the placebo effect.

Answer (score 1):

3-conductor cable allows you to send and receive both balanced audio and phantom power. I would do this with the 8423 cable for best results.

Comment: What do you mean? Pay attention to you?

Comment: How about not bringing your 35 days of stack membership to bear when trying to hijack someone else's question and making it all about your needs and wants?

Comment: seeing as you are so keen on seeing this, why not provide an answer of your own, rather than making demands on others?

Comment: Better yet, why not add to the stack and ask a question of your own?

Comment: I'd love to have been a fly on the wall during that discussion ;)) tbh, you could use shielded 2-core for a regular XLR, but 3-core is 'nicer'. Tag the ground to the shield when you're soldering. [For the OP] XLR wiring has a hot, cold & earth/ground. Balanced cabling requires all three. Phantom power to a mic not requiring it is simply 'ignored' in all but old ribbon mics. Others simply don't care.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you saying if I supply phantom power to a dynamic microphone, it will just ignore it and do nothing? I thought it'd break it :o That's nice to know. I don't know what to do with this knowledge though, lol.

Comment: Skye - yes. This was standardised a long time ago. For anything made in the last 50 years or so, if a mic doesn't need phantom, it will just 'ignore it'. This is especially useful if you have a board with a single switch for all the phantom.

Comment: @Skye-AT "... it will just ignore it and do nothing?" It should do. You do need to have a balanced dynamic mic and balanced cabling all the way to the phantom power source. If any part is unbalanced you risk running the phantom power through the microphone coil.